# Qt program not invoked by cron

Tags: cron, qt

I had a simple Qt program, when running, it shows a simple window with a countdown timer.  If you might be interested in the code, please see [here](https://github.com/gongzhitaao/typebreak).

I had crontab line

```
* * * * * /home/my-user-name/Documents/bin/program
```

When executing the comment `/home/my-user-name/Documents/bin/program`, the program runs correctly.  But it's not invoked by the `cron`.  I have multiple cron jobs, all run smoothly except this one.

My question is:

Do you have any idea what might cause this?  Qt problem?  `PATH` problem?

*I have searched around for `cron`, and tried almost all the tips.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that cron runs in a text environment. There are a few different approaches for that, depending on what your machine is running.

set a display variable:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/my-user-name/Documents/bin/program
```

set up a password-less ssh key-pair and do

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/ssh -y user@localhost /home/my-user-name/Documents/bin/program
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks. BTW, Any document for this?

Comment: You're welcome. I can't think of any document that states this explicitly. It's more of a matter of knowing how Unix/Linux works, and realising that crond runs before X. So, even if a cron job gets run as a user, it won't inherit the knowledge of the users X-Session (or environment variables that are set after you log in).

Comment: @gongzhitaao When you run a program in UNIX world, you can before running initialize a env variabel such as : `root@debian:/opt /ldoce5# myvar=googooli  ./ldoce5-bin  &` Each program when that run, has a directory with its PID in /proc/, in my example: `/proc/21959/` and each process has a file named `environ`,  i use cat environ , i saw the following result: myvar=googooliXDG_VTNR=7ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-mohsenXDG_SESSION_ID=10SSH_AGENT_PID=6196TERMINATOR_UUID (yes a set of variable and you can see myvar)